# ¿Cómo puedo mandar a llamar un componente desde un boton en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hola soy nuevo en React y quiero realizar un "To Do List" sencillo, para ello cuento con un input text y un boton. La idea es que cuando escriba en el input, de click al boton y este muestre una tarjeta la cual contendrá lo que recientemente se escribió y así sucesivamente se vayan generando más tarjetas.

Hasta el momento unicamente tengo guardado lo que escribe el usuario en el input text, quisiera saber como puedo mandar a llamar un componente (que es la tarjeta) por medio del boton. Cabe señalar que estoy usando una class App y mi función componente que quiero mandar a llamar esta fuera de la clase.

Si hay algo que no tiene sentido se aceptan sugerencias y de todo, gracias :)

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
import React, {useState, Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Container, FormControl, InputLabel, Input, Button} from '@material-ui/core';

function toDo(props) {
  return <div>
          <p> To Do </p>
          <p> Description: {props.name}</p>
        </div>;
}

class App extends Component {

  state = { task: "", };

  valueToState = (target) => {
    this.setState( () => {
      return { [target.name]: target.value};
    });
  };
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>

      <div>
        <p>To Do List</p>
      </div>
 
      <div>
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel>New task</InputLabel>
          <Input 
            onChange={event => this.valueToState(event.target)} 
            name = "task" 
            type = "text"/>
        </FormControl>
        <Button 
          onClick = {toDo(this.state.task)} 
          variant="contained" 
          color="primary">
            Add
        </Button>
      </div>

    </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas a tener en cuenta en tu código.

Lo primero sería acomodar el lugar de la función `toDo()` y meterla dentro de la clase `App`.

Otro detalle es sacarle la palabra `function` y definirla directamente como un método del componente.

El segundo punto que me gustaría cambiar, es la manera en la que estás definiendo el estado `task`.

Como estás trabajando con los componentes de clases de React, debería estar dentro del `constructor()` de la clase y también agregar el método `super()`.

El tercer ajuste que también se le puede hacer a tu código es la manera en la que declaras el método `onClick` en el botón **Add**.

Debe ser una función que  ejecute otra función, en este caso el método `toDo()`, y no hay que olvidar usar la palabra reservada `this` al llamar un método del componente.

En este caso quedaría así:

`onClick={() => this.toDo(this.state.task)}`

Teniendo en cuenta todas esas consideraciones, te propongo esta manera de hacer lo que buscas:

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  Container,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  Input,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";

class App extends Component {
  // state = { task: "" };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { toDoList: [] };
  }

  valueToState = (target) => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { [target.name]: target.value };
    });
  };
  toDo(props) {
    console.log(props);
    let newItem = this.state.toDoList.concat(props);
    this.setState({ toDoList: newItem });
    // return <div>
    //         <p> To Do </p>
    //         <p> Description: {props.name}</p>
    //       </div>;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>To Do List</p>
        </div>

        <div>
          <FormControl>
            <InputLabel>New task</InputLabel>
            <Input
              onChange={(event) => this.valueToState(event.target)}
              name="task"
              type="text"
            />
          </FormControl>
          <Button
            onClick={() => this.toDo(this.state.task)}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Add
          </Button>
          <ul>
            {this.state.toDoList.map((item) => (
              <li>{item}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit new]

Ahora analicemos un poco lo que hace este código.

Básicamente toma el valor del input, y al accionar el botón **Add** se lleva dicho valor a la función `toDo()`, y esa función guarda ese valor en el estado `toDoList` que es un array.

Luego se imprime en el DOM el contenido de ese array con una función `.map`.

```
  <ul>
    {this.state.toDoList.map((item) => (
      <li>{item}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
```

Ejecuta todo el código en SandBox, pruébalo y mira si cumple con lo que buscabas.

PD: Te recomiendo que aprendas a usar los [Hooks de React](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html). Se usan en la últimas versiones de React y simplifican mucho el trabajo de crear componentes.

Comment: Super clara la explicación, si me sirvió de mucho, me falta practica ya iré mejorando, le agradezco mucho su tiempo :)